# JQuery Keyframe Animation: object from latest position always appear at the first keyframe position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, keyframe

I need help with JQuery keyframe. I'm trying to create an animation of a bus that stops at each station, but my bus keep appearing at the first position in an image as shown below. Due to low fps, you will only see it appears at the first position the second time I click the button, but in reality it always appear there when I click the button.

I'm using this library https://github.com/Keyframes/jQuery.Keyframes btw.

How can I fix this? Any helps would be appreciated.

```
<div style="margin-top:30px">
    <input id="txt" type="text" />
    <button id="btn">Register</button>
    <div id="messages">
    </div>
    <button id="startpin">StartPIN</button>
    <div>
        <img id="pin21" class="pinJQ" src="~/Images/pin_21_n.png" />
        <div style="display:flex; flex-direction:row;text-align:justify;justify-content: space-between">
            <div style="display:flex;" id="B1">B01</div>
            <div style="display:flex;" id="B2">B02</div>
            <div style="display:flex;" id="B3">B03</div>
            <div style="display:flex;" id="B4">B04</div>
            <div style="display:flex;" id="B5">B05</div>
            <div style="display:flex;" id="B6">B06</div>
            <div style="display:flex;" id="B7">B07</div>
            <div style="display:flex;" id="B8">B08</div>
            <div style="display:flex;" id="B9">B09</div>
            <div style="display:flex;" id="B10">B10</div>
            <div style="display:flex;" id="B11">B11</div>
            <div style="display:flex;" id="B12">B12</div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

<style>
    .pinJQ {
        position: relative;
        height: 20px;
        width: 20px;
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var multiplier = 0;

    $('#startpin').on('click', () => {
        var nextStation = multiplier + 9

        $.keyframe.define([{
            name: 'pin-move',
            'from': { 'left': multiplier + '%' },
            'to': { 'left': nextStation + '%' },
        }]);

        $('#pin21').playKeyframe({
            name: 'pin-move',
            duration: '1s',
            delay: '0s',
        });

        multiplier = multiplier + 9
    })

</script>
```

[image]

Comment: Add `animation-fill-mode: forwards;` to `playKeyframe()`

Comment: I tried fillMode:'forwards' in playKeyframe, but it's still the same :(